# How do I create a view in which 'name' is replaced with 'new_name' if 'old_name' exist in the conversion table?

Tags: sqlite, sql-view

I would like to create a view that looks like the original `tree_prototype` table.
In this view the `name` should be set to the `new_name` value from the `tree_prototype_conversion` table if there is a matching `old_name`. If there is no match, the original `name` should stay.

I think I could do this in a case if  I join on the `name` and `old_name` fields but that doesn't seem like the right approach. I feel like I am missing the obvious, and a CASE isn't it.

These are the tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tree
(
    tree_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    tree_prototype_id INTEGER,    
    FOREIGN KEY (tree_prototype_id) REFERENCES tree_prototype (tree_prototype_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tree_prototype
(
    tree_prototype_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    height REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT(10) CHECK (height > 0)
);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tree_prototype_conversion
(
    old_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    new_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE    
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_tree_prototype
    ON tree_prototype (name);
```

What I would like is a view that is both of these in one:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS tree_prototype_converted AS
SELECT tree_prototype_id,
       name,
       height
FROM tree_prototype
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT old_name FROM tree_prototype_conversion);

CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS tree_prototype_converted AS
SELECT tree_prototype_id,
       new_name as name,
       height
FROM tree_prototype_conversion
JOIN tree_prototype as conversion on old_name=name;
```

After writing the CASE variant, my IDE suggested this:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS tree_prototype_converted AS
SELECT tree_prototype_id,
       coalesce(new_name, name) as name,
       height
FROM tree_prototype
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tree_prototype_conversion as conversion on old_name = name;
```

That looks right. Is it?